# Post on a forum with Python 3.5 Requests library

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I've been trying to post on a topic in a specific forum, using Python 3.5 with requests library.

The issue is, when I look at the Form Data from the post request that actually posts the message to the forum, I see lots of data. Not sure where to get it from in order to pass it on the request using Python

The code I have is the following

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:

    urlpost = "http://forum.outerspace.com.br/index.php?threads/t%C3%B3pico-oficial-heroes-of-the-storm.355675/add-reply"

    c.get(urlpost)
    cks = c.cookies
    headers={}
    headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
    headers["Referer"] = "http://forum.outerspace.com.br/index.php"
    mypost = dict(message_htlm="<p>hi</p>",_xfRelativeResolver="http://forum.outerspace.com.br/index.php?threads/t%C3%B3pico-oficial-heroes-of-the-storm.355675/")
    c.post(urlpostt,headers=headers, cookies=cks, data=mypost)
```

The data passed on the request when I post a message is:

```
message_html: 'My Message'
_xfRelativeResolver: 'this is the referer'
attachment_hash:7ef8a3ea0dff5cc4fbaa32b8dd702d1f: #not sure where it came from
last_date:1448677064 #not sure where it came from
last_known_date:1448677064 #not sure where it came from 
_xfToken:224338,1453416035,1bddacdfc5e0040f5b288f1a8e6e6cbfcad78200 #not sure where it came from
_xfRequestUri:/index.php?threads/como-comprar-sem-dificuldades-jogos-assinaturas-etc-para-xbox.435327/
_xfNoRedirect:1
_xfToken:224338,1453416035,1bddacdfc5e0040f5b288f1a8e6e6cbfcad78200 #not sure where it came from
_xfResponseType:json
```

Any though on how to get all these values?

Comment: Check which are CSRF tokens (usually come as headers when you GET the form page). Overall, check headers you get when you login and when you load the form page.

Comment: I suggest you do a real post via firefox/chrome, and find what data is posted but ignore those values without an input tag or id.